# What is the difference between regular expression $(x + y)^*$ and $(x^*y^*)$?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

What is the difference between regular expression $(x + y)^*$ and $(x^*y^*)$ ?

Comment: What branch is this?

Comment: Hint: Does the string $yx$ match both regular expressions?

Comment: @ErickWong So the order is different. $yx$ matches the first one but not the second, right ?

Comment: @Altaïr Yes, now can you see exactly what types of strings belong to $x^*y^*$?  You should be able to describe it in simple words.

Comment: @ErickWong But there is something I don't understand. Isn't the symbol + means OR ? So $(x+y)^*$ would represent language that consists of strings that has any number of x's or strings that has any number of y's but not strings that has x's and y's together.

Comment: @Altaïr, no. $x + y$ is *an* $x$ or a $y$, $(x + y)^*$ is any number of the enclosed, i.e., repeat ($x$ or $y$).

Comment: @Altair Consider what vonbrand says.  Now contrast that with $(x^*) + (y^*)$, which is exactly what you were describing.  Order of association matters!

Comment: @ErickWong Got it. So if I wanted to define a regular expression that represents the intersection of $((x+y)^*)z)$ and $((x^*y^*)z^*)$, the regular expression would be $(x^*y^*)z$. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Altaïr Yes, looks fine.  A lot of people would write it as simply $x^*y^*z$ because concatenation is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are words on the alphabet $A$, the regular expression $(x + y)^*$ denotes the submonoid of $A^*$ generated by $x$ and $y$. Thus 
$$
(x + y)^* = \{1, x, y, xx, xy, yx, yy, xxx, xxy, xyx, \ldots\}
$$ 
where $1$ is the empty word. The regular expression $x^*y^*$ denotes the product of $x^*$ by $y^*$. Therefore 
$$
x^*y^* = \{x^ny^m \mid n \geqslant 0, m \geqslant 0\}
$$
Thus $(x + y)^* = x^*y^*$ if and only if $xy = yx$, which is known to be equivalent to the fact that $x$ and $y$ are powers of the same word, that is $x = u^p$ and $y = x^q$ for some $p,q \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to exist several syntaxes for regular expressions which is why one should be a bit careful. What I would guess is that $+$ in this context means "or". In many programming languages "or" is instead written as a vertical line | so that can give some confusion.

If my interpretation is correct then $(x+y)^*$ means " 'either x or y' repeated any number of times" and $x^*y^*$ means x repeated any number of times followed by y repeated any number of times.

The difference is that the first one can find strings which have $x$s coming after the first $y$. The second one the order is important: first any number of $x$s and then as many $y$s we can find.

Examples:

$xyxyxy$ should only be matched by the first one but $xxyyy$ by both.

Answer (score 0):

have you read the [manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts) ?

- +: 1 or more
- *: 0 or more
- ?: 0 or 1 (if part of your expression above: ambiguous).

So:

- (x+y)* can produce  (), xy, xxxy, xyxxy, etc. Never more than 1 y in a row, any number (>0) of x between.
- (x*y*) can produce (), x, y, xx, yy, xyy, etc. I.e., 0 or more x, then 0 or more y.

Comment: Well putting negative points, it would be nice to explain what is wrong. (and if the wrongness is technical or formal). thanks.

Comment: The first part is possibly correct but see @mathreader's answer to understand why there's a strong chance it doesn't match the manual.  However, "any string made of $x$ and $y$" is simply wrong, since it can't produce $yx$ (this might be a language problem: in English at least, certainly $yx$ qualifies as a string made of $x$ and $y$).

Comment: I did considered 'standard' regexp (wikipedia, js, c, shell, ...).  and yx  perfectly matches x*y*.   ( is x0y1x1)

Comment: No, $yx$ does not match the standard regexp $x^* y^*$: `echo yx | grep '^x*y*$'` returns no lines.

Comment: AAAAAAAAH, you right, I was confusing with (x\*y\*)* !!! (as in my current program...) The presence of () was tempting to extrapolate !

Comment: -> fixed in the answer.